# How to access the item from the property

Tags: jquery, json

```
    {
  "label": "",
  "sku": "true",
  "xxx": {
    "promo": "",
    "specs": [],
    "original":"300.00"
  },
  "xxx": {
    "promo": "",
    "specs": [],
    "original":"350.00"
  },
  "xxx": {
    "promo": "",
    "specs": [],
    "original":"400.00"
  },

  "promo": "",
  "promo-img": "",
  "specs": [],
  "original":"350.00"
}


if(product["json"].sku["original]){
 object += '<div class="original-price">'+ product["json"].sku["original"] +'</div>';

            var product = {
                "json": product_promo_details_json
            };

            which will take json to parse.
```

Wanted to access the item "original" from the sku list. but it returns undefined of original. Not sure where it went wrong >.< Appreciate quick help

Comment: There are multiple `xxx` key on your json.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try to access using `json["original"]`

```
var json =    {
  "label": "",
  "sku": "true",
  "xxx": {
    "promo": "",
    "specs": [],
    "original":"300.00"
  },
  "xxx": {
    "promo": "",
    "specs": [],
    "original":"350.00"
  },
  "xxx": {
    "promo": "",
    "specs": [],
    "original":"400.00"
  },

  "promo": "",
  "promo-img": "",
  "specs": [],
  "original":"350.00"
}


if(json["original]){
 object += '<div class="original-price">'+ json["original"] +'</div>';
```

Comment: is there any possibility of accessing specific sku's original without var json?

Comment: @joe can you please post how you are declaring the object in your code

Comment: it is somewhat confidential cos i m working on client's. Trying to find how to access to sku

Comment: @joe post prototype of it how is your parent object?

Answer (score 0):

It is the simple way to access that property:

```js
var json =    {
  "label": "",
  "sku": "true",
  "xxx": {
    "promo": "",
    "specs": [],
    "original":"300.00"
  },
  "xxx": {
    "promo": "",
    "specs": [],
    "original":"350.00"
  },
  "xxx": {
    "promo": "",
    "specs": [],
    "original":"400.00"
  },

  "promo": "",
  "promo-img": "",
  "specs": [],
  "original":"350.00"
}

var object='';
if(json["original"]){
object += '<div class="original-price">'+ json["original"] +'</div>';
console.log(object);
}
```